# Why community has not posted anything yet?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

Like any other stack exchange sites, I assumed [community](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) to be an active member of this site. This site is growing and [needs](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3698/movies-tv) more questions and answers. So communitys' Q/A can add potential to the site. But I found community has not posted anything at all; neither question, nor answer. Why is community so silent here? We expect much more from him.

Comment: The very user page that you link to here says 'I'm not really a person' and explains what it does.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a read of this post: [What is the Community User](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8291/154443) and you will understand why.

It can't ask questions - it is not a human! It just randomly pokes/bumps questions that maybe haven't had enough attention.

Comment: I love that Community has edited an answer about Community.